# tsconfig.json difference between include and rootDir

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

From the documentation it's said that `include` specifies an array of filenames or patterns to include in the program (i.e. in the compilation process). Similarly, `rootDir` is the path to the folder with the source code of the app to be included in the compilation process.

```
  "include": ["./src/"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "test/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
  }
```

What's their difference then?

Answer (score 20):

The `include` top-level option defines files that will be included. It is relative to `.tsconfig.json` and defaults to `**`, meaning all files in the project. Files outside `include` will **not** be compiled.

The `compilerOptions.rootDir` option defines the root of the tree at `outDir`. By default, it uses the common path among the included folders. This means in a project with two files `src/services/user.ts` and `src/services/auth.ts`, `rootDir` would default to `src/services/` (ie., the longest common path segments of all input files). The output directory would look like this:

```
dist
├── auth.js
└── user.js
```

Manually setting `rootDir` to `src` would instead produce this output directory:

```
dist
└── services
    ├── auth.js
    └── user.js
```

Finally, having files outside of `rootDir` included by the `include` option would emit an error:

```
error TS6059: File '~/project/outside.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '~/project/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Matched by include pattern '**/*' in '~/project/tsconfig.json'
```

Comment: Is there away ti have files outside of rootDir? Except this one: https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS6059